# Is there a minimum version for MySQL on AWS RDS below which incremental snapshots are not possible?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, backup

In particular is it possible to take incremental snapshots on AWS RDS for MySQL 5.5?

Comment: Why would it not be?  Are you experiencing a specific problem?

Comment: I was informed by someone who had a MySQL 5.5 DB on rackspace that they couldn't take incremental snapshots and needed to have MySQL 5.6 or above. I tried going through AWS documentation but I'm still not sure whether that was just an issue on rackspace of if it is the case on AWS as well.

Comment: All snapshots on RDS, for all engines, all versions, are incremental.  You can't make an RDS snapshot that is *not* incremental.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up.